# Difference between function annotations

Tags: typescript

I've found that there are a few ways I can represent a function property:

```
var f1: (...args:any[]) => any;
var f2: { (...args:any[]):any; }
var f3: Function;
```

My understanding is that `f1` is a function type, `f2` is a function interface, and `f3` is a type. Is there any difference between these, or is it essentially different mechanisms of TypeScript to say the same thing? Otherwise, when would you use one over the others?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there any difference between these, or is it essentially different mechanisms of TypeScript to say the same thing

All are equivalent. Basically `Function` is the least safe and `(...args:any[]) => any;` essentially captures the same thing (I'd prefer `Function` to indicate that you are not guaranteeing any safety).

## More

Between the two:

```
var f1: (...args:any[]) => any;
var f2: { (...args:any[]):any; }
```

First is just a shorthand syntax for the second. The second syntax exists to allow you to declare *overloads* which cannot be done with the first syntax.

Comment: Pedantry: The first two are exactly equivalent, but the third is different in some edge cases that aren't worth going into.

Comment: @RyanCavanaugh thanks Ryan. I am curious about the edge cases please 

Comment: In `f = x => 3;`, `x` gets an *implicit* any when `typeof f` is `Function`, but not when it's `typeof f1`

Comment: @RyanCavanaugh nice. Thanks 